# Revert to closest non intersecting position

Tags: xna, collision-detection, movement

First, let me start by saying:

> *Please forgive me if this question have already been asked. I've tried to search but didn't find any solution. (It might be due to my lack of terms).*

I have two circles with `r` radius, `p(x,y)` position and `v(x,y)` velocity. I need a formula for calculating position **p3** if the first circle (blue) intersects with the second circle (red), thus placing it as close as possible next to the red circle without intersecting.

Any ideas?

```
Vector2 c1 = new Vector2((p1.X + r1), (p1.Y + r1));
Vector2 c2 = new Vector2((p2.X + r2), (p2.Y + r2));
bool intersects = ((Vector2.Distance(c1, c2)) < (r1 + r2));
```

[image: Circles]

Comment: This should probably be moved to Mathematics.SE. I think you'd get better results.

Comment: Do you want to have the red circle travel to the end of its velocity step for this frame, and the blue circle to come as close as possible to *that* position without intersecting? Or do you want to stop them both where they would have been at the moment of contact? (Generally sometime between the previous physics step and this one)

Comment: @DMGregory As it stands: In this frame I just want to revert to `p3` and set it's velocity to `0,0`. The red circle will continue without any changes made to its position or velocity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The math is a bit easier if we center our coordinate system on the final position of the red circle, which I'll call p2 here. We can treat the red circle as stationary, given OP's comment above.

So we're looking for a time t when the blue circle's position is exactly r1 + r2 away from the red circle at p2. We can find the position once we know this time.

Let's define:

```
p = p1 - p2
v = v1
r = r1 + r2
```

So we're trying to solve:

```
||p + t*v|| = ||r||
```

Or equivalently:

```
(p + t*v)^2 = r^2
p^2 + 2(t)(p · v) + (t^2)(v^2) = r^2
t^2(v^2) + t(2p · v) + p^2 - r^2 = 0
```

Now we can write some code to solve this using the [quadratic formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_formula).

```
float t = deltaTime;

float a = Vector2.dot(v, v);
float b = 2f * Vector2.dot(p, v);
float c = Vector2.dot(p, p) - r*r;

float discriminant = b*b - 4f*a*c;

if(discriminant >= 0f) // Otherwise there is no solution: the circles never touch.
{
   float denominator = 1f/(2f * a);
   float center = -b * denominator;
   float offset = Sqrt(discriminant) * denominator;

   // In general there are two solutions, so here I'll arbitrarily select the point closest to the blue circle's start position
   // even if that means it's pushed backward, or pushed beyond where its velocity could take it this frame.    
   if(center >= 0)
   {          
       t = Min(t, center - offset);
   }
   else
   {
       t = Max(t, center + offset);
   }
}

p3 = p1 + t * v1;
```

The discriminant check, mins & maxes above should give the correct behaviour even if you use this code for circles that never intersect. But if you're pre-filtering for intersecting pairs, you can simplify them a little.

Note that this will not work if p1's velocity is zero. In that case, you may want to set:

```
p3 = p2 + Vector2.normalize(p1 - p2) * (r1 + r2);
```

...which can also fail if p1=p2, so you'll want some default separation vector if this kind of pathological case can happen.